# I lost to Mid-Boss. Do I want to proceed with NG+?

Tags: disgaea

Losing to Vyers counts as a bad "end" in Disgaea, and lets you start the game over in NG+ as soon as 1-4.

Is this something that you actually want? [This comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59918/whats-a-good-way-to-level-up-new-characters#comment85132_59918) mentions something about a new character, but I'm back to 1-4 and I haven't really noticed anything particular. (If it matters, and it seems that it does, I'm playing Disgaea PC.)

Comment: I think the only reason to do this would be get Pleinair, assuming that's she's playable in the PC version and you know or can figure out the secret to recruiting her. Otherwise you're just grinding levels again you could've replayed without restarting the story.

Comment: @RossRidge [she _is_ in the game in the list of NPCs I can rename](http://i.imgur.com/zCvuefU.jpg), I dunno if that's good enough.

Comment: @RossRidge ...however [I cannot repro the unlocking process](https://gfycat.com/UncomfortableOddBlowfish) (fixed link)

Comment: to my recollection 1-4 is the earliest you can unlock a new cycle so you might want to get a particular characters/systems from the beginning to play with throughout the game which can only be unlocked in a second cycle. also my memory of the game escapes me but isn't there an endings list which the bad endings also get listed in, if so then if your trying to 100% the game it is an ending you want to get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the PC version of the game, there are no real benefits to losing on 1-4. The DS version of the game allows you to unlock Prinny Commentary (where on the top screen of the DS, more dialogue is shown) and Pleinair for completing your first cycle. Since you can get Pleinair without needing to start a new cycle, and the Prinny Commentary is not available in the PC version, there's no benefits to be had there.

... However, the gameover music of the ending might be "special" in some sort of way - if it's a track you haven't heard yet, you'll unlock it. Like this, you could unlock the option to buy it in the music shop early. That said, you probably don't have the cash (100k HL) to buy any of the instrumental background tracks, nevermind any of the songs (10M? It's a lot of zeros).

I looked at an [ending guide on gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/589678-disgaea-hour-of-darkness/faqs/23835) (beware, SPOILERS!). It mentions that "it's got a vocal track you won't hear otherwise," so I guess that losing to Mid-Boss at stage 1-4 would be the easiest way to unlock that song.

Comment: Man it sounds like they removed a lot of fun in the PC version

Comment: Prinny commentary was a GREAT reason to replay the story.

Comment: Maybe it's coming from an update, but I got Pleinair in my team as soon as my first playthrough (no ng+).

Comment: Shywim in the DS version, you need to start a new cycle. But yeah, I'll update my answer.